# Find out irregular entries with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, filtering, aggregate-functions

I am having some human error entries in my table. Some missing a zero, some has more material than it should be, and so on. So I am trying to scan throughout a table to find some error in an entry groups.
Table goes like this:

```
| Work Order | Product | Material Qty
---------------------------------
| 1          | Item A  | 10
| 2          | Item A  | 25
| 3          | Item A  | 12
| 4          | Item A  | 9
| 5          | Item X  | 52
| 6          | Item X  | 20
| 7          | Item X  | 23
| 8          | Item X  | 24
| 9          | Item X  | 2
| 10         | Item Z  | 20
| 11         | Item Z  | 5
---------------------------------
```

Now, the WO and WO item are not that sequential, I write it as sequential here only for examples.

As you can see, those item A should have number around 10, give or take some. Item X should be around 22, give or take some, meanwhile the query should tag Item Z as all suspicious since there are not enough data to correlate. So I need to isolate WO number 2, 5 and 9, 10 and 11 for people to audit. Any idea how?

I have been trying to create an average of them, and using a percentage to eliminate them. But sometimes, percentage number are too varies. And in case of item Z, there are not enough data to choose which number are normal number, and which number are irregular numbers, and I need to tag both of them for verification, in which case, reducing down to percentage won't help.

Also, if I reduce them to variant percentage against average, its spread are still too wide to tag one of them.

Any ideas? Because I am really stuck this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a statistical basis, you probably want to start with the `STDEV` [standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) function.

```
select * 
from

(       
select *,
   AVG(qty) OVER( Partition by product) av,
   STDEV(qty) OVER( Partition by product) sd,
   COUNT(*) over (Partition by product) c
 from yourtable
) v
where ABS(qty-av)>sd or c<3
```